# Reference to another Brush from one Brush in xaml

Tags: wpf, styles, resourcedictionary, brush

Is it possible to directly reference to a Brush value from another Brush in my resource dictionary, without using a Color definition (or to be exact, copy one brush resource into another)?

For example, I have a Brush definition:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PanelBackgroundBrush" Color="White"/>
```

And I have a couple of other brushes I'd like to be exact the same as "PanelBackgroundBrush", something like so:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FolderColor" [BrushToCopy]="{StaticResource PanelBackgroundBrush}"/>
```

So that both "PanelBackgroundBrush" and "FolderColor" are using color white.

I understand this can be somehow achieved by using a common Color definition.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No way I know of to copy the brush itself, but as you say you can copy properties of the brush:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FolderColor" Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource PanelBackgroundBrush}}"/>
```

The above should have the same effect.

Comment: For a LinearGradientBrush you can do this:    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItem.Static.Background" EndPoint="{Binding EndPoint, Source={StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}}" StartPoint="{Binding StartPoint, Source={StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}}" GradientStops="{Binding GradientStops, Source={StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}}"/>

Comment: Worked here perfectly. Would be a bad choice if I changed every Color resource to a SolidColorBrush since I can reference this way?

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
<Color x:Key="colorCommon">Red</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="scb1" Color="{StaticResource colorCommon}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="scb2" Color="{StaticResource colorCommon}" />
```

(Note that you could specify the regular Color properties in the Color).

However, if you are just using the same color with multiple SolidColorBrush objects, I guess I would question why you would do this, unless it is for some future flexibility.  Otherwise, you are just creating extra work and readability issues for yourself.